# Qt Browser stack when dropping link to QMainWindow

Tags: c++, qt, drag-and-drop

I have simple drag and drop functions implemented in QmainWindow the reference taken from [here](http://sector.ynet.sk/qt4-tutorial/dnd.html) and [here](http://developer.qt.nokia.com/wiki/Drag_and_Drop_of_files)
all i want to do is to accept valid url and open QDialog when the url dropped .
but when the url drooped and the QDialog poped up the browser is stocked in the background until i close the QDialog .  this is wrong the browser should be free all the time.
here is my code :

```
void MainWindow::dragMoveEvent(QDragMoveEvent *event)
{
 
    if (event->mimeData()->hasFormat("text/html")) 
    {   
        event->acceptProposedAction();
    }
    else
    {
        event->ignore();
    }
}
void MainWindow::dragEnterEvent(QDragEnterEvent *event)
{
    // accept just text/uri-list mime format
    if (event->mimeData()->hasFormat("text/html"))
    {   
        event->acceptProposedAction();
    } 
    else
    {
        event->ignore();
    }
}
void MainWindow::dragLeaveEvent(QDragLeaveEvent *event)
{
   
     event->accept();

    
}
void MainWindow::dropEvent(QDropEvent *event)
{
    QList<QUrl> urlList;
    QString fName;
    QStringList pathList;
    QFileInfo info;
    QString suffix;
         
        if (event->mimeData()->hasFormat("text/html"))
        {
            urlList = event->mimeData()->urls(); // returns list of QUrls
            // if just text was dropped, urlList is empty (size == 0)
            
            if ( urlList.size() > 0) // if at least one QUrl is present in list
            {
                    QString url = urlList.at(0).toString();
                    event->acceptProposedAction();
                    openDialog(url); // THIS IS THE FUNCTION THAT I OPEN THE QDIALOG window 
                 
                 
            }
        }
        //event->acceptProposedAction();
}

void MainWindow::openDialog(QString& slink)
{
    
        QHash<QString,QVariant> DataMap;         
        QString link = slink;
        DataMap.insert("m_webpage",link);
         
        PublishToDialog* pPublishToDialog = new PublishToDialog(this);
        pPublishToDialog->Init(DataMap);
        if(pPublishToDialog->exec() != QDialog::Accepted)
        {
                     
        }
}
```

when i remove the call to the QDialog , so every thing is working fine .
and the browser doesn't stuck. i even tryed as suggested using signal/slot put again
when i start the QDialog when drop invoked the browser stucked!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What exactly is `PublishToDialog`? I would assume that it is a custom dialog implementation of yours that inherits `QDialog`. And given this line:

```
pPublishToDialog->exec() != QDialog::Accepted
```

This opens the dialog as a `modal dialog`. A modal dialog is blocking and will block the execution of the current thread until some action is performed on the dialog. Instead of using a modal dialog, you should use a non-modal dialog. Since I am still not sure if `PublishToDialog` inherits `QDialog` or what else, I am just going to assume it is. Here is what you could do:

```
PublishToDialog* pPublishToDialog = new PublishToDialog(this);

// Make it a non-modal dialog
pPublishDialog->setModal(false);

// Connect it to a slot to handle whenever the user performs some action on it
QObject::connect(pPublishDialog, SIGNAL(finished()), this, SLOT(handleDialogAction());
pPublishDialog.show();
```

You will have to implement `handleDialogAction` in your code. At the same time, you may want to make `pPublishDialog` a class-member as you will need it to access `QDialog::reuslt` in `handleDialogAction`.

Comment: it is implementation of QDialog, and i do wish it will act as modal dialog that blocking the QMainWindow . but not the browser that i draged the link from . in my case the browser is stack until i close the PublishToDialog (QDIalog) window

Comment: I tryied what you suggest , but still no good . even when im using signal/slot the browser stuck. the QDialog is the problem . when i remove the call every thing is working fine .

Comment: Could you post your code to pastebin or something? Like the entire class with the signals/slots? And no, what you are suggesting is not possible, because a modal dialog will block the main thread in which the QApplication runs its event loop. You block that, everything gets stuck.

Comment: found the solution , simple using open() method of the QDialog